# How to find the declaration of an Ident using go/analysis?

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree, static-analysis, go-toolchain

I use go/analysis to create my own static analysis tool. I still don't know how to find the def information from ast.Ident.

Here is my testdata

```
package randomcheck
func xxx() {
}
func demo()  {
    xxx()
}
```

And my own analyzer

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "go/ast"
    "golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis"
    "golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/inspect"
)

var name string // -name flag
var Analyzer = &analysis.Analyzer{
    Name:     "fft",
    Requires: []*analysis.Analyzer{inspect.Analyzer},
    Run:      run,
}
//pass.Fset.Position(name.Pos())
func run(pass *analysis.Pass) (interface{}, error) {
    for _, f := range pass.Files {
        ast.Inspect(f, func(node ast.Node) bool {
            name,ok := node.(*ast.Ident)
            if !ok {
                return true
            }
            if name == nil {
                return true
            }
            if pass.TypesInfo.Defs[name] != nil {
                fmt.Println("def: " ,name)
            } else {
                fmt.Println("use: ", name)
            }
            return true
        })
    }

    return nil, nil
}


output:

use:  randomcheck
def:  xxx
def:  demo
use:  xxx
```

I need to find the def info **def:xxx** directly from **use:xxx**, but I can't find useful information in pass.TypesInfo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for the `ObjectOf` method? Here's your version with some modifications:

```
func run(pass *analysis.Pass) (interface{}, error) {
    for _, f := range pass.Files {
        ast.Inspect(f, func(node ast.Node) bool {
            name, ok := node.(*ast.Ident)
            if !ok {
                return true
            }
            if name == nil {
                return true
            }

            fmt.Println("ident:", nodeString(node, pass.Fset))
            obj := pass.TypesInfo.ObjectOf(name)
            fmt.Println(obj)
            if obj != nil {
                fmt.Println("  pos:", pass.Fset.Position(obj.Pos()))
            }
            return true
        })
    }

    return nil, nil
}

// nodeString formats a syntax tree in the style of gofmt.
func nodeString(n ast.Node, fset *token.FileSet) string {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    format.Node(&buf, fset, n)
    return buf.String()
}
```

When run on your sample input file, it shows:

```
ident: randomcheck
<nil>
ident: xxx
func command-line-arguments.xxx()
  pos: /home/eliben/temp/randomcheck.go:3:6
ident: demo
func command-line-arguments.demo()
  pos: /home/eliben/temp/randomcheck.go:5:6
ident: xxx
func command-line-arguments.xxx()
  pos: /home/eliben/temp/randomcheck.go:3:6
```

Note that the last id `xxx` is found as a reference to the top-level function `xxx()` with its proper position, etc.

Comment: Thank you very very much.  Your code works fine.